# Mongoose - convert date field to array of dates, with the existing entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, casting

I have a collection of documents, that looks like this:

```
{
  name: String,
  phoneNumber: String,
  myDate: Date
}
```

And this is how an actual entry would look like:

```
{
  name: 'John Doe',
  phoneNumber: '(402)-123-4444',
  myDate: 2020-08-31T08:54:47.000+00:00
}
```

And I have about 1000 entries in my db. Now I want to change the date field to an array of dates, and I want to modify all the entries in my db to be something like this `myDate: [Date]`. I want to keep the existing entry from the date field, but move it inside of an array. And I don't want to do it manually, any way I can do this with mongoose?

I tried something like `Model.update({}, { $set: { myDate: [] } })`, but I don't know what to use inside the array to keep the existing entry, and not to add something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will on one-time activity so I wanna propose two steps answer here,

Step 1. : Change the type of field from the mongo/shell as,

```
> db.collection.find().forEach(function(individualDocument) {
   db.collection.update(
      { _id: individualDocument._id },
      { "$set": { "myDate": [individualDocument.myDate] } }
   );
})
```

Step 2: Update your mongoose model as you tried ,

```
{
  name: String,
  phoneNumber: String,
  myDate: [Date]
}
```

OR

```
myDate: { type: Array, default: [Date] }
```